# How can I fit long equation in table in beamer

Tags: tables, beamer, fit

I would like to insert a pretty table in my beamer presentation by using [Beautiful table samples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112343/beautiful-table-samples). But my equation does not fit in one line of the table.

```
\documentclass[leqno,mathserif,hyperref={pdfpagemode=FullScreen},
xcolor={dvipsnames,svgnames,table}]{beamer}
%\usepackage{concrete}
 \usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}%      pour les maths
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{eulervm}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\newcommand{\E}{\mathrm{E}}
\newcommand{\Var}{\mathrm{Var}}
\newcommand{\Cov}{\mathrm{Cov}}
\newcommand{\Expect}{{\rm I\kern-.3em E}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}
\newcommand*{\everymodeprime}{\ensuremath{\prime}}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\tcbset{tab1/.style={fonttitle=\bfseries\large,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!75!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title,freelance,frame code={
\foreach \n in {north east,north west,south east,south west}
{\path [fill=red!75!black] (interior.\n) circle (3mm); };},}}

\tcbset{tab2/.style={enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!50!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tcolorbox}[tab2,tabularx={X},title=Very Long Développements text ,boxrule=0.9pt]
Processus of something : $X_t=\mathds{1}_{\{X> t\}},\ t\in I$\\\hline\hline
theory of something : ${K(s,t)=\Cov(X_{s},X_{t})=\sum_{n\geq 1}\lambda_{n}\psi_{n}(t)\psi_{n}(s)}$   \\\hline
theory of something : $K(s,t)=\Cov(X_{s},X_{t})=\sum_{n\geq 1}\lambda_{n}\psi_{n}(t)\psi_{n}(s)$   \\\hline
4 \\\hline\hline
5    \\\hline
6  \\\hline
7  \\\hline
8 \\\hline
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for. You have a large equation. Are you looking for something that would scale it down? Anyway, in trying to process your MWE, I got an option clash. Can you please fix this?

Comment: yes me too i got an option clash and i don't know how to fix it

Comment: Remove `\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}` to get rid of the option clash. Still, there are further errors like an unknown `\mathds`.

Answer (score 2):

It might be enough to just reduce the fontsize in the `tcolorbox` a bit, for example by using `fontupper=\small`.

```
\documentclass[leqno,hyperref={pdfpagemode=FullScreen},
xcolor={dvipsnames,svgnames,table}]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}%      pour les maths
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{eulervm}

\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\newcommand{\E}{\mathrm{E}}
\newcommand{\Var}{\mathrm{Var}}
\newcommand{\Cov}{\mathrm{Cov}}
\newcommand{\Expect}{{\rm I\kern-.3em E}}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Tr}{Tr}
\newcommand*{\everymodeprime}{\ensuremath{\prime}}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french]{babel}

%\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\tcbset{tab1/.style={fonttitle=\bfseries\large,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!75!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title,freelance,frame code={
\foreach \n in {north east,north west,south east,south west}
{\path [fill=red!75!black] (interior.\n) circle (3mm); };},}}

\tcbset{tab2/.style={enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!50!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{tcolorbox}[tab2,tabularx={X},title=Very Long Développements text ,boxrule=0.9pt, fontupper=\small]
Processus of something : $X_t={1}_{\{X> t\}},\ t\in I$\\\hline\hline
theory of something : ${K(s,t)=\Cov(X_{s},X_{t})=\sum_{n\geq 1}\lambda_{n}\psi_{n}(t)\psi_{n}(s)}$   \\\hline
theory of something : $K(s,t)=\Cov(X_{s},X_{t})=\sum_{n\geq 1}\lambda_{n}\psi_{n}(t)\psi_{n}(s)$   \\\hline
4 \\\hline\hline
5  \\\hline
6  \\\hline
7  \\\hline
8 \\\hline
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
\end{frame}
```

[image]