# Nice tables in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, color, tabularx, incompatibility

I liked the approach shown here. [beautiful tables in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112343/beautiful-table-samples). But when I use it in beamer class, tabularx conflicts with xcolor. What is the solution?

Comment: if you want help with an error, please supply a small document that reproduces the error, what does "conflict" mean here?

Answer (score 1):

Beamer loads `xcolor` by itself. So if you want to use specific `xcolor` options (and the approach does) you have to pass them to beamer and not load `xcolor` again with these settings.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer} % <-- set xcolor options here

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\tcbset{tab1/.style={fonttitle=\bfseries\large,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!75!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title,freelance,frame code={
\foreach \n in {north east,north west,south east,south west}
{\path [fill=red!75!black] (interior.\n) circle (3mm); };},}}

\tcbset{tab2/.style={enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!50!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Nice Tables}
\begin{tcolorbox}[tab2,tabularx={X||Y|Y|Y|Y||Y}]
Group & One     & Two     & Three    & Four     & Sum      \\\hline\hline
Red   & 1000.00 & 2000.00 &  3000.00 &  4000.00 & 10000.00 \\\hline
Green & 2000.00 & 3000.00 &  4000.00 &  5000.00 & 14000.00 \\\hline
Blue  & 3000.00 & 4000.00 &  5000.00 &  6000.00 & 18000.00 \\\hline\hline
Sum   & 6000.00 & 9000.00 & 12000.00 & 15000.00 & 42000.00
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```