# how to adjust the header of a table ?

Tags: tables, tabu

I'm trying to use a table in my these. 
I have used this code from this [list of tables](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112343/beautiful-table-samples) :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
 \definecolor{tableHeader}{RGB}{211, 47, 47}
\definecolor{tableLineOne}{RGB}{245, 245, 245}
\definecolor{tableLineTwo}{RGB}{224, 224, 224}

 \newcommand{\tableHeaderStyle}{
\rowfont{\leavevmode\color{white}\bfseries}
\rowcolor{tableHeader}
}


 \begin{document}
  \taburowcolors[2] 2{tableLineOne .. tableLineTwo}
  \tabulinesep = ^4mm_3mm
  \everyrow{\tabucline[.4mm  white]{}}

  \begin{tabu} to \textwidth {l >{\bfseries}X[r, 1] X[4] l}
    \tableHeaderStyle
    & Titre  & description & \\
    & \textbf{But} & Sécuriser l’accès à l’application \\

   & \textbf{Acteurs} & Tous les acteurs\\
 ....
 \end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

But I had this result :

I don't know why the header is not adjusted . could someone help me please ? 
[image]

Comment: your table is inconsistent, you define it with 4 columns but only use effectively 2. your problem comes from the fact that your header row has 4 columns used with the first and last empty, whereas the subsequent row, only have 3 with the first one empty.