# How to remove unwanted blank margin at the end of the row?

Tags: tables, tabularx, tcolorbox, multirow, cline

Inspired by [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112359/61804), here is an MWE that show a visible margin between the end of the row and the right hand side of the table. That's annoying. Any idea how to remove that?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Fancy table
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112343/beautiful-table-samples
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hsize=.6\hsize}X}

\tcbset{tab2/.style={enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
        colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!50!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
        coltitle=black,center title}}


\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[tab2,tabularx={Z || Z | Z | Z},title=AAA,width=0.7\textwidth]
    BBB & BBB & BBB & BBB \\ \hline\hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{XXX} & AAA & AAA & AAA \\ \cline{2-4}
    &  & AAA & AAA \\ \cline{2-4}
    &  & AAA & AAA
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Change the definition of Z column `\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem  comes a misunderstanding of `>{\hsize=0.6\hsize}X`: it is made for `X` columns of unequal lengths and the values work as barycentric coordinates: their sum must be equal to the number of columns (4, here). Their sum is equal to `2.4` instead! As all your columns have equal widths, remove this specification and  it will be fine:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}%
\tcbset{tab2/.style={enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
        colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!50!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
        coltitle=black,center title}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[tab2,tabularx={Z || Z | Z | Z },title=AAA, width=0.7\textwidth]
    BBB & BBB & BBB & BBB \\ \hline\hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{XXX} & AAA & AAA & AAA \\ \cline{2-4}
    & & AAA & AAA \\ \cline{2-4}
    & & AAA & AAA
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Additionally, note the `usenames` option for `xcolor` is deprecated as it's tthe default now. I added the `table` option, which avoids you having to load explicitly `colortbl`.