# How do I generate a caption instead of title?

Tags: tables, captions, tcolorbox

In the following example, I want to generate `Table 3.1: AAA` as the caption instead of the plain title `AAA`. To clarify further, I do not want teh caption to be place above or below the table, but the title should be substituted by the caption text. Any idea on how to achieve that?

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Fancy table
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112343/beautiful-table-samples
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}

\tcbset{tab2/.style={enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
        colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!50!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
        coltitle=black,center title}}


\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[tab2,tabularx={Z || Z | Z | Z},title=AAA,width=0.7\textwidth]
    BBB & BBB & BBB & BBB \\ \hline\hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{XXX} & AAA & AAA & AAA \\ \cline{2-4}
    &  & AAA & AAA \\ \cline{2-4}
    &  & AAA & AAA
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array, caption, chngcntr, etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{tcolorbox}{
\captionsetup{font={sf, bf}}}

\counterwithin{table}{section}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\usepackage{multirow}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{Z}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}%
\tcbset{tab2/.style={enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
        colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!50!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
        coltitle=black,center title}}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{section}{3}

\begin{tcolorbox}[tab2, tabularx={Z || Z | Z | Z}, before title =\vspace*{-2pt}, after title=\vspace*{-13pt}, title=\captionof{table}{AAA},width=0.7\textwidth]
    BBB & BBB & BBB & BBB \\ \hline\hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{XXX} & AAA & AAA & AAA \\ \cline{2-4}
    & & AAA & AAA \\ \cline{2-4}
    & & AAA & AAA
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I can see the thickness of the title bar is more when caption is added. Is it possible to reduce it back to the original thickness?

Comment: @Holmes.Sherlock: Yes. I removed the  `skip=0pt` from `caption`, and used the `after title` and `before title` keys instead. Please see my updated answer. However, it shouldn't be so tight in my opinion.