# How to minimize a text in a table?

Tags: tables, fonts, text

My document looks like this: [image]
Is there any way to minimize the font to make it look more attractive?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You can try to use for the table `\small` size or you can visit the link https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112343/beautiful-table-samples. Another suggestion: use `\log` instead of `log`.

Comment: At some point you appear to have gotten out of sync with math mode and text mode.  As always, a minimal working example would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use the package `tabu`. It is very simple to use.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}

Without specifying width for last column:
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{| l | l | l | l |}
    \hline
    Day & Min Temp & Max Temp & Summary \\ \hline
    Monday & 11C & 22C & A clear day with lots of sunshine.
    However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures. \\ \hline
    Tuesday & 9C & 19C & Cloudy with rain, across many northern regions. Clear spells 
    across most of Scotland and Northern Ireland, 
    but rain reaching the far northwest. \\ \hline
    Wednesday & 10C & 21C & Rain will still linger for the morning. 
    Conditions will improve by early afternoon and continue 
    throughout the evening. \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

With width specified:
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | p{5cm} |}
    \hline
    Day & Min Temp & Max Temp & Summary \\ \hline
    Monday & 11C & 22C & A clear day with lots of sunshine.  
    However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures. \\ \hline
    Tuesday & 9C & 19C & Cloudy with rain, across many northern regions. Clear spells 
    across most of Scotland and Northern Ireland, 
    but rain reaching the far northwest. \\ \hline
    Wednesday & 10C & 21C & Rain will still linger for the morning. 
    Conditions will improve by early afternoon and continue 
    throughout the evening. \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Visit this link: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables