# tcolorbox: auto adjusting column lengths

Tags: tabularx, tcolorbox

I am using the code of a good answer provided to [Beautiful table samples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112343/beautiful-table-samples) question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\tcbset{tab1/.style={fonttitle=\bfseries\large,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!75!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title,freelance,frame code={
\foreach \n in {north east,north west,south east,south west}
{\path [fill=red!75!black] (interior.\n) circle (3mm); };},}}

\tcbset{tab2/.style={enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!50!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[tab2,tabularx={X||Y|Y|Y|Y||Y}]
Group & One     & Two     & Three    & Four     & Sum      \\\hline\hline
Red   & 1000.00 & 2000.00 &  3000.00 &  4000.00 & 10000.00 \\\hline
Green & 2000.00 & 3000.00 &  4000.00 &  5000.00 & 14000.00 \\\hline
Blue  & 3000.00 & 4000.00 &  5000.00 &  6000.00 & 18000.00 \\\hline\hline
Sum   & 6000.00 & 9000.00 & 12000.00 & 15000.00 & 42000.00
\end{tcolorbox}   

\end{document}
```

I need to write simple different words in each cell, but whatever the length of my words are, the columns always are of equal widths. I wonder how I can adjust the code so that each column width becomes as long as the longest word contained in one of its cells.

Comment: Of course they are of the same width, since you're using `X` and `Y` columntypes, the later being nothing different than `X` again.

Comment: I thought `X` and `Y` position the text either to left of right ... thank you for the hint

Comment: The typical way to adjust columns to their natural width is the `tabulary` package, but `tcolorbox` doesn't support that as a possibility. See e.g. [Auto-fit table column widths based on content](//tex.stackexchange.com/a/16867)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use an `X` column in the first column of headings so that takes up any required width of the table, and for the others use `l` (or `r` or `c` or whatever) so they fit to the natural width of the content.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}

\tcbset{tab1/.style={fonttitle=\bfseries\large,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!75!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title,freelance,frame code={
\foreach \n in {north east,north west,south east,south west}
{\path [fill=red!75!black] (interior.\n) circle (3mm); };},}}

\tcbset{tab2/.style={enhanced,fonttitle=\bfseries,fontupper=\normalsize\sffamily,
colback=yellow!10!white,colframe=red!50!black,colbacktitle=Salmon!40!white,
coltitle=black,center title}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[tab2,tabularx={X||r|r|r|r||r}]
Group & One     & Two     & Three    & Four     & Sum      \\\hline\hline
Red   & 1000.00 & 2000.00 &  3000.00 &  4000.00 & 10000.00 \\\hline
Green & 2000.00 & 3000.00 &  4000.00 &  even wider cell & 14000.00 \\\hline
Blue  & 3000.00 & wider-words &  5000.00 &  6000.00 & 18000.00 \\\hline\hline
Sum   & 6000.00 & 9000.00 & 12000.00 & 15000.00 & 42000.00
\end{tcolorbox}   

\end{document}
```

Comment: Clever and effective approach, thank you a lot.