# data description table

Tags: tables

Please how do I produce a table like this? Thanks.[image]

Comment: With LaTeX, a table is a type of float.  What you want is a tabular or tabularx.  The only thing tricky here is that the caption is not centered and appears to be inside the tabular (or after \hrule).

Comment: Hello John, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately I'm clueless about tables in latex. Btw, it need not be the exact same thing as the image. Anything similar will do.

Comment: [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112343/76279) are some examples of tables with similar formatting (and the corresponding latex code) to what you have shown. You may be able to adapt the samples for your content.