# how to generate a table as below in latex?

Tags: tables

I am new to latex and working on my thesis. Can anybody show me the codes how to build this table, I want to do exactly the same thing as in the picture

[image]

Comment: where is your table? what you try so far?  welcome to tex.se!

Comment: You can produce such tables with the `booktabs` package, see for example this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112514/36296

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: Check this link. Very useful information about building tables. https://en.m.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables.

Comment: I checked, very nice but it was not like this table :p

Comment: but given link in @phollox is very useful for start to learn how to write tables. at list on basis of showed tables' codes you can prepare own table and than ask for help where you are suck. so far, as i see from your question and responses on received answers (no one you accept!), you actually looking for service "write-table-instead-of-me" ...

Answer (score 1):

it mimic your table design, however, you need to populate with correct texts and numbers in cells ...

[image]

code is quit sophisticated (since your table is not simple), however on the site are many very similar tables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{my tavle}\label{tab:scoring}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
  \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                        l
                        S[table-format=-1.3]
                   *{2}{S[table-format= 1.3]}
                        S[table-format=-1.2]
                        S[table-format=-1.3]
                   *{2}{S[table-format= 1.3]}
                            }
    \toprule
    &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{some text}   &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{some text}   \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-5}
    \cmidrule(l){6-8}
    &   {\thead[b]{text\\ text}}
        &   {\thead[b]{text}}
            &   {\thead[b]{text}}
                &   {\thead[b]{text\\ text}}
                    &   {\thead[b]{text\\ text}}
                        &   {\thead[b]{text\\ text}}
                            &   {\thead[b]{text\\ text}}                    \\
    \midrule
text    & -1.234    & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.12  & 0.123 & 0.123 & 1.234         \\
some longer text (with seven words)
        & -1.234    & 0.123 & 0.123 & 0.12  & -2.00 & 0.123 & 1.234         \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular*}
  \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\small
  \note:   each variable ...
  \source:   Authors' calculations ...
  \end{tablenotes}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

i strongly encourage you to read some introductory text about table settings. for example [LaTeX/Tables](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables) or [Tables](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Tables) as well used packages documentations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have (I started inputting the data but then I was not bothered anymore) Also I forgot how to do a thick line so I just did a double line:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}

\caption{SCORING FACTORS AND SUMMARY STATSTICS FOR VARIABLES ENTERING THE COMPUTATION
OF THE FIRST PRINCIPAL COMPONENT}

\smallskip{}

\begin{tabular}{l>{\centering}p{1.4cm}cc>{\centering}p{2.2cm}> {\centering}p{1.3cm}>{\centering}p{1.3cm}>{\centering}p{1.3cm}}
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{All India} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Means}\tabularnewline
\cmidrule(r){2-5}
\cmidrule(l){6-8}
& Scoring Factors & Mean & SD & Scoring Factor $\times$ SD & Poorest 40\% & 
Middle 40\% & Richest 20\%\tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule 
Own Clock/Watch & 0.270 & 0.533 & 0.499 & 0.54 & 0.164 & 0.739 & 0.985\tabularnewline
Own Bicycle & 0.130 & 0.423 & 0.494 & 0.26 & 0.264 & 0.510 &         0.621\tabularnewline
Own Radio &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Own Television &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Own Sewing Machine &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Own Motorcycle &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Own Refigerator &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Own Car &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Drinking Water From Pump/Well &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Drinking Water From Open Source &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Drinking Water From Other Source &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Flush Toilet &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Pit Toilet/Latrine &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
None/Other Toilet &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Main Source of Lighting Electric &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Number of Rooms in Dwelling &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Kitchen a Seperate Room &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Main Cooking Fuel Biomass (Wood/Dung/Coal) &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Dwelling All High-Quality Materials &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Dwelling All Low-Quality Materials &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Own >6 acres Land &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Economic Status Index &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\emph{Note: }bla bla bla

\emph{Source: }Bla bla bla
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

And this is what it looks like (EDIT IT NO LONGER LOOKS LIKE THIS, THERE IS A GAP IN THE LINE BETWEEN INDIA AND MEANS):
[image]

Comment: uouuu thats greatttt, thank you very much. Dont worry about the data because I will put my data, I just wanted the code. Also, do you know how to separate the line of (all india) and (means) in two different lines as above

Comment: @Zarko has done it well in his table, but I will edit mine to include that feature

Comment: I have a problem, I dont know how but the latex displays only half of the table

Answer (score 0):

Just a tiny example that might serve you

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption[Add your short title for table index.]{This title can be longer.}\label{tab:example}
    \begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
        \toprule
        &  &  &  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Red} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Blue} \\
        \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-8}
        Case & Nomeclature & $\frac{L_\text{out}}{D}$ & $F_\text{mid}$ & Data & Nodes & Data & Nodes \\ 
        \midrule 
        1 & Case 1 & 25 & 1.00 & 3756 & 3133 & 3736 & 33983 \\
        2 & Case 2 & 35 & 1.50 & 5034 & 4209 & 5004 & 40649 \\
        3 & Case 3 & 45 & 1.80 & 6296 & 5263 & 6276 & 56513 \\
        \bottomrule 
    \end{tabular} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```