# the table showing only in half of the page

Tags: tables, booktabs

Problem with the table it shows only in half

[![][1]][1]

```
\documentclass[11pt, english, singlespacing, ]{MastersDoctoralThesis} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 

\renewcommand{\chaptermarkformat}{\thechapter.~}

\usepackage{mathpazo} 
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex} % Use the bibtex backend with the authoryear citation style (which resembles APA)

\addbibresource{example.bib} 

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} 

\usepackage{dirtytalk}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-10}

\renewcommand{\abovechapterskip}{\vspace*{2pt}}

\renewcommand\rightmark{Albania: Transition from Equality to Inequality}
\renewcommand\leftmark{Klisman Ndoje}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}

\usepackage{array, caption, hhline, cellspace,  booktabs}


%--------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath, amsfonts, mathtools, amssymb} %% Math packages 



%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGIN SETTINGS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    inner=2.5cm, % Inner margin
    outer=3.8cm, % Outer margin
    bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset
    top=1.5cm, % Top margin
    bottom=1.5cm, % Bottom margin
    %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}

\caption{SCORING FACTORS AND SUMMARY STATSTICS FOR VARIABLES ENTERING THE COMPUTATION
OF THE FIRST PRINCIPAL COMPONENT}

\smallskip{}

\begin{tabular}{l>{\centering}p{1.4cm}cc>{\centering}p{2.2cm}> {\centering}p{1.3cm}>{\centering}p{1.3cm}>{\centering}p{1.3cm}}
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{All India} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Means}\tabularnewline
\cmidrule(r){2-5}
\cmidrule(l){6-8}
& Scoring Factors & Mean & SD & Scoring Factor $\times$ SD & Poorest 40\% & 
Middle 40\% & Richest 20\%\tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule 
Own Clock/Watch & 0.270 & 0.533 & 0.499 & 0.54 & 0.164 & 0.739 & 0.985\tabularnewline
Own Bicycle & 0.130 & 0.423 & 0.494 & 0.26 & 0.264 & 0.510 &         0.621\tabularnewline
Own Radio &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Own Television &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Own Sewing Machine &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Own Motorcycle &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Own Refigerator &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Own Car &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Drinking Water From  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Drinking Water From  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Drinking Water From  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Flush Toilet &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Pit Toilet/Latrine &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
None/Other Toilet &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Main Source of Lighting Electric &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Number of Rooms in Dwelling &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Kitchen a Seperate Room &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Main Cooking Fuel Biomass  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Dwelling All High-Quality Materials &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Dwelling All Low-Quality Materials &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Own >6 acres Land &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Economic Status Index &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\emph{Note: }bla bla bla

\emph{Source: }Bla bla bla
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably your table is too wide for the `\textwidth` you have. You can play with different parameters to make it fit between the margins, but it's hard to say which without a full code.

Comment: the full code of the document? or of the table?

Comment: The relevant part of the code – this includes the document class, font size, packages determining the layout, &c.

Comment: below you will find the whole code

Comment: if you would consider my answer on your question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442333/how-to-generate-a-table-as-below-in-latex) , this will not happen.

Comment: yes, it didnt happen, but when I started filling the text, the space between the columns disappeared

Comment: then you have three options: (i) use smaller fonts in table, (ii) increase `\textwidth` locally in table  or rotate table (use `landscape` page or`sidewaystable` environment. please edit your question and in table example provide code for rows with the longer text in cells.

Comment: I edited the question and now the code of the document and table is showed

Answer (score 2):

based on my answer on your question [how-to-generate-a-table-as-below-in-latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/442333/how-to-generate-a-table-as-below-in-latex). added are

- real names in columns headers
- real items in the first column
- use of `threeparttable`, which enable to use `\tnote` (in column headers, see mwe below)
- use os smaller font size (since your table is a bit to wide for space of `\textwidth`)

  ```
  \documentclass[11pt, english, singlespacing]{book}% i havent your document class {MastersDoctoralThesis}

  \usepackage{babel}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage{graphicx}


  \usepackage[paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
              inner=2.5cm, % Inner margin
              outer=3.8cm, % Outer margin
              bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset
              top=1.5cm, % Top margin
              bottom=1.5cm, % Bottom margin
              showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
              ]
              {geometry}

  \usepackage{siunitx}
  \usepackage{booktabs, makecell}
  \usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}

  \usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

  \begin{document}
     \begin{table}[htb]
      \begin{threeparttable}
  \caption{SCORING FACTORS AND SUMMARY STATISTICS FOR VARIABLES ENTERING THE COMPUTATION
  OF THE FIRST PRINCIPAL COMPONENT}
  \label{tab:score}
      \small
      \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
      \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                          l
                          S[table-format=-1.3]
                     *{2}{S[table-format= 1.3]}
                          S[table-format=-1.2]
                          S[table-format=-1.3]
                     *{2}{S[table-format= 1.3]}
                              }
      \toprule
      &   \multicolumn{4}{c}{All India}   &   \multicolumn{3}{c}{Means}   \\
      \cmidrule(r){2-5}
      \cmidrule(l){6-8}
      &   {\thead[b]{Scoring\\ Factors}}
          &   {\thead[b]{Mean}}
              &   {\thead[b]{SD}}
                  &   {\thead[b]{SF\tnote{a}\\$\times$SD}}
                      &   {\thead[b]{Poorest\\ \SI{40}{\%}}}
                          &   {\thead[b]{Middle\\ \SI{40}{\%}}}
                              &   {\thead[b]{Richest\\ \SI{20}{\%}}}      \\
      \midrule
  Own Clock/Watch
      & 0.270 & 0.533 & 0.499 & 0.54  & 0.164 & 0.739 & 0.985              \\
  Own Bicycle
      & 0.130 & 0.423 & 0.494 & 0.26  & 0.264 & 0.510 & 0.621              \\
  Own Radio
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &                   \\
  Own Television
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &                   \\
  Own Sewing Machine
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &                   \\
  Own Motorcycle
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &                   \\
  Own Refigerator
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &                   \\
  Own Car
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &                   \\
  Drinking Water From
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &                   \\
  Drinking Water From
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &                   \\
  Drinking Water From
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &                   \\
  Flush Toilet
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &                   \\
  Pit Toilet/Latrine
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &                   \\
  None/Other Toilet
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &                   \\
  Main Source of Lighting Electric
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &                   \\
  Number of Rooms in Dwelling
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &                   \\
  Kitchen a Seperate Room
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &                   \\
  Main Cooking Fuel Biomass
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &                   \\
  Dwelling All High-Quality Materials
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &                   \\
  Dwelling All Low-Quality Materials
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &                   \\
  Own >6 acres Land
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &                   \\
  Economic Status Index
      &       &       &       &       &       &       &                   \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular*}
    \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\small
    \item[a] SF: Scoring Factors
    \note   each variable ...
    \source   Authors' calculations ...
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
  \end{table}

  \end{document}
  ```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possibility for your table. I don't of course have your class, so I used `book` instead, and added `\usepackage{mathpazo}` (I'm not sure if the font used is actually Palatino, I'm terrible at recognizing fonts, but I don't think it's standard Computer Modern at least.)

I used `S` columns (from `siunitx`) instead of `p` columns, and reduced the fontsize and `\tabcolsep` (space between columns), as well as removing the padding at the start and end of each row.

For the multi-line column headings, I used a macro made by egreg in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19678, for making manual linebreaks in a table cell.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}

% font package added for example only
\usepackage{mathpazo} % don't use in your actual document


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%   MARGIN SETTINGS
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\geometry{
    paper=a4paper, % Change to letterpaper for US letter
    inner=2.5cm, % Inner margin
    outer=3.8cm, % Outer margin
    bindingoffset=.5cm, % Binding offset
    top=1.5cm, % Top margin
    bottom=1.5cm, % Bottom margin
    %showframe, % Uncomment to show how the type block is set on the page
}

\newcommand{\specialcell}[2][t]{% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19678
  \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}

\caption{SCORING FACTORS AND SUMMARY STATSTICS FOR VARIABLES ENTERING THE COMPUTATION
OF THE FIRST PRINCIPAL COMPONENT}

\smallskip%
\footnotesize % reduce fontsize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3.5pt} % modify space between columns (default 6pt I think)

\begin{tabular}{@{}l *{7}{S} @{}} % remove padding at start/end of row, use S columns instead of p
\toprule 
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{All India} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Means}\tabularnewline
\cmidrule(r){2-5}
\cmidrule(l){6-8}
& {\specialcell{Scoring\\Factors}} & {Mean} & {SD} & {\specialcell{Scoring\\Factor\\$\times \mathrm{SD}$}} & 
  {\specialcell{Poorest\\40\%}} & {\specialcell{Middle\\40\%}} & {\specialcell{Richest\\20\%}} \tabularnewline
\midrule
\midrule 
Own Clock/Watch & 0.270 & 0.533 & 0.499 & 0.54 & 0.164 & 0.739 & 0.985\tabularnewline
Own Bicycle & 0.130 & 0.423 & 0.494 & 0.26 & 0.264 & 0.510 &         0.621\tabularnewline
Own Radio &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Own Television &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Own Sewing Machine &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Own Motorcycle &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Own Refigerator &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Own Car &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Drinking Water From  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Drinking Water From  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Drinking Water From  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Flush Toilet &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Pit Toilet/Latrine &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
None/Other Toilet &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Main Source of Lighting Electric &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Number of Rooms in Dwelling &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Kitchen a Seperate Room &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Main Cooking Fuel Biomass  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Dwelling All High-Quality Materials &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Dwelling All Low-Quality Materials &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Own >6 acres Land &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
Economic Status Index &  &  &  &  &  &  & \tabularnewline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\smallskip % add some vertical space

\emph{Note: }bla bla bla

\emph{Source: }Bla bla bla
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it works, than you sir :)