# Any suggestions on how to make this table prettier and suggestions on whether it's better to make it fit in 1 or 2 columns

Tags: tables

How can I make this table look prettier and more elegant than this and do you think it's better to make it fit into one or two columns? I am also opened to making it span over two columns if you think this is better.
[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran} 
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts


\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{changepage}


%\usepackage{algpseudocode} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ctable}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ctable
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\newcommand{\var}{\textit}
\newcommand{\proc}{\textbf}
\newcommand{\prop}{\texttt}
\newcommand{\plusplus}{{+}{+}}% Other options: 
\newcommand*\ita[1]{\textit{#1}}
%\usepackage{xcolor}                             % changed
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell, multirow}% new
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{textcomp}


\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}
\newcommand\mc[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{//#1}



\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\caption{XCallers and XCallees for Methods in Figure}
\label{tab:XCallersXCalleesExample}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Method\#} & \textbf{1-StartGPS} & \textbf{2-Start} & 
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}3-Reserve\\ Seat\end{tabular}} & 
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}4-Set\\ Passenger\\ Info\end{tabular}} & 
\textbf{5-Start} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}6-Book\\ 
 Ticket\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}7-Book\\ 
 Ticket\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
    \textbf{XCallers} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}2-Start \\ 5- 
 Start\end{tabular} & Empty & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}6-BookTicket \\ 7- 
 BookTicket\end{tabular} & Empty & Empty & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}4- 
 Set\\ Passenger\\ Info\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}4-Set\\ 
 Passenger\\ Info\end{tabular} \\ \hline
    \textbf{XCallees} & Empty & 1-StartGPS & Empty & \begin{tabular}[c] 
  {@{}c@{}}6-BookTicket \\ 7-BookTicket\end{tabular} & 1-StartGPS & 3- 
 ReserveSeat & 3-ReserveSeat \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass and the relevant packages. Regarding "prettier", you might want to follow the suggestions by Mico (usage of less lines, usage of `booktabs`) on your previous question.

Comment: Common for beautiful(subjective) tables is that they have very few lines - certainly not vertical lines like that. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112343/beautiful-table-samples

Comment: Regarding the table being too wide for the column, you could play around with decreasing the font size and the `\tabcolsep`. However, I doubt, that the table will fit into a single column without applying some more changes. More methods can be found here: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144)

Comment: yur table is far to wide to be fit in present form in one column. you have tow options: (i) set it over two columns (with ˙table*` float) or rewrite table on the way, that you interchange columns and rows.

Answer (score 5):

what is nice looking table is personal opinion. apparently (as follows from accepted answers on your previous question) you don't like professional looking tables.

Anyway, as i told you in comment, your table is to wide that can be fit into one column as it is. so, according to *my* taste i suggest you to write it over two columns as follows:

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{stfloats}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{table*}[b]
    \centering
\caption{XCallers and XCallees for Methods in Figure}
\label{tab:XCallersXCalleesExample}
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l *{7}{c}}
    \toprule
\thead[bl]{Method \#}
    & \thead[b]{StartGPS}       & \thead[b]{Start}
    & \thead[b]{Reserve Seat}   & \thead[b]{Set\\ Passenger Info}
    & \thead[b]{Start}          & \thead[b]{Book Ticket}
    & \thead[b]{Book Ticket}                                \\
    & (1)   & (2)   & (3)   & (4)   & (5)   & (6)   & (7)   \\
    \midrule
XCallers
    & \makecell{2-Start\\
                5-Start}        & Empty
    & \makecell{6-BookTicket\\
                7-BookTicket}   & Empty
    & Empty                     & 4-Set Passenger Info
    & 4-Set Passenger Info                              \\
    \addlinespace
XCallees
    & Empty                     & 1-StartGPS
    & Empty                     & \makecell{6-BookTicket\\
                                            7-BookTicket}
    & 1-StartGPS                & 3-ReserveSeat
    & 3-ReserveSeat                                     \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table*}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

or consider the second possibilities: interchange rows and columns in your table:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{booktabs, makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\setcellgapes{2pt}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}
\usepackage{stfloats}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \makegapedcells
\caption{XCallers and XCallees for Methods in Figure}
\label{tab:XCallersXCalleesExample}
\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}l ll }
    \toprule
Method \#       & \thead{XCallers}      & \thead{XCallees}      \\
    \midrule
1-StartGPS      & \makecell[tl]{2-Start\\
                                5-Start}& Empty                 \\ 
2-Start         & Empty                 & 1-StartGPS            \\ 
3-Reserve Seat  & \makecell[tl]{6-BookTicket\\
                                4-Set Passenger Info}   
                                        & Empty                 \\
4-Start         & Empty                 & 4-Set Passenger Info  \\
5-Start         & Empty                 & 1-StartGPS            \\
6-Book Ticket   & 4-Set Passenger Info  & 3-ReserveSeat         \\
7-Book Ticket   & 4-Set Passenger Info  & 3-ReserveSeat         \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: @user3406764 This is how professional, *really nice* tables look like. Classical, clean layout, no distracting clutter.

Comment: @Sveinung, thank you for nice words!

Comment: In my opinion, the first table (over two columns) is the best, It blends very well to the page layout, and placing at the bottom of the page is a good choice. you may consider removing the side bearing by placing @{} in the beginning and end of the preamble.

Comment: @Sveinung, you are right.  in my first attempt i consider this, but letter i remove them, now don't know why.  i will wait for while to op response and than correct table code as you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Here there is my simple proposal. With `%<----adding` you can see my changhes. The most important is the use the `\resizebox` to decrease the size of the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran} 
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{changepage}

\usepackage{lipsum}%<-------------------adding

%\usepackage{algpseudocode} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ctable}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ctable
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\newcommand{\var}{\textit}
\newcommand{\proc}{\textbf}
\newcommand{\prop}{\texttt}
\newcommand{\plusplus}{{+}{+}}% Other options: 
\newcommand*\ita[1]{\textit{#1}}
%\usepackage{xcolor}                             % changed
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell, multirow}% new
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{textcomp}


\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}
\newcommand\mc[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{//#1}



\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}


\begin{document}


\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[]
\centering%<-------------------adding
\caption{XCallers and XCallees for Methods in Figure}
\label{tab:XCallersXCalleesExample}
\resizebox{0.45\textwidth}{!}{\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}%<-------------------adding
    \hline
    \textbf{Method\#} & \textbf{1-StartGPS} & \textbf{2-Start} & 
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}3-Reserve\\ Seat\end{tabular}} & 
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}4-Set\\ Passenger\\ Info\end{tabular}} & 
\textbf{5-Start} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}6-Book\\ 
 Ticket\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}7-Book\\ 
 Ticket\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
    \textbf{XCallers} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}2-Start \\ 5- 
 Start\end{tabular} & Empty & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}6-BookTicket \\ 7- 
 BookTicket\end{tabular} & Empty & Empty & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}4- 
 Set\\ Passenger\\ Info\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}4-Set\\ 
 Passenger\\ Info\end{tabular} \\ \hline
    \textbf{XCallees} & Empty & 1-StartGPS & Empty & \begin{tabular}[c] 
  {@{}c@{}}6-BookTicket \\ 7-BookTicket\end{tabular} & 1-StartGPS & 3- 
 ReserveSeat & 3-ReserveSeat \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}}
 \end{table}
\lipsum[2-3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Personally, I would not recommend using `\resizebox` in order to resize tables as this method will lead to inconsistent font sizes throughtout the document.

Comment: @leandriis I agree with you. However, it depends on the number of tables that are inserted in the document. If there are two or three, it could be a solution. Surely mine is just a proposal, and it certainly won't be the best :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano,  do you see https://wiert.me/2014/04/03/andre-vatter-google-wie-tabellen-eigentlich-aussehen-sollten-%EF%BB%BF/ ? on web can find more similar presentation about table settings.  in answers of Mico, Bernard (to name only a few) you can see many nice designed tables. they are worth to red. (i nullify dovn-wote).

Comment: @Zarko You're a very dear friend. I always thank you very much. I have tried to give my interpretation of the solution. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Don't attempt to use `\resizebox` for tables, this a really bad advice to give to users because it will give very ugly results.

If you want to keep this layout (the clean layout from Zarko is much better) manually choose a smaller font size and reduce the inter column space:

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran} 
\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts


\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{changepage}


%\usepackage{algpseudocode} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ctable}% http://ctan.org/pkg/ctable
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\newcommand{\var}{\textit}
\newcommand{\proc}{\textbf}
\newcommand{\prop}{\texttt}
\newcommand{\plusplus}{{+}{+}}% Other options: 
\newcommand*\ita[1]{\textit{#1}}
%\usepackage{xcolor}                             % changed
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell, multirow}% new
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{textcomp}


\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand\mytab[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}} #1 \end{tabular}}
\newcommand\mc[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}}
\renewcommand{\algorithmiccomment}[1]{//#1}



\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08em
T\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\caption{XCallers and XCallees for Methods in Figure}
\label{tab:XCallersXCalleesExample}
\tiny
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2.7pt}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    \textbf{Method\#} & \textbf{1-StartGPS} & \textbf{2-Start} & 
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}3-Reserve\\ Seat\end{tabular}} & 
\textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}4-Set\\ Passenger\\ Info\end{tabular}} & 
\textbf{5-Start} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}6-Book\\ 
 Ticket\end{tabular}} & \textbf{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}7-Book\\ 
 Ticket\end{tabular}} \\ \hline
    \textbf{XCallers} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}2-Start \\ 5- 
 Start\end{tabular} & Empty & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}6-BookTicket \\ 7- 
 BookTicket\end{tabular} & Empty & Empty & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}4- 
 Set\\ Passenger\\ Info\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}4-Set\\ 
 Passenger\\ Info\end{tabular} \\ \hline
    \textbf{XCallees} & Empty & 1-StartGPS & Empty & \begin{tabular}[c] 
  {@{}c@{}}6-BookTicket \\ 7-BookTicket\end{tabular} & 1-StartGPS & 3- 
 ReserveSeat & 3-ReserveSeat \\ \hline
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: personally is a bad business card of a user criticizing harshly the work of another. I have simply written my own thought.