# Tables with paragraphs

Tags: tables

What's the best way to create a table with a lot of data (text) ?

[image]

Comment: Take a look at the `tabularx` package.

Comment: Perhaps also think about whether this is the best way to present this information?

Comment: None. For a lot of text is more convenient a nested list or plaint text well structured in sections. But  you are looking  for  `tabulary` (similar to `tabularx`, but allow desigual widths and any type of alignment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution with `tabulary`:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\bf\bfseries
\usepackage{array,geometry,tabulary,booktabs,lipsum,microtype} 
\begin{document}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\begin{tabulary}{\linewidth}{>{\bf}l*3{>{\parskip1em}L}}\toprule
Klasse & 
\bf FooFooFoo & 
\bf FooFoo & 
\bf FooFooFoo \\\midrule
Niv\.a 1 & 
\lipsum[1][1-2]\par\lipsum[2][1-3]  & 
\lipsum[3][1-3]\par\lipsum[4][1-3] & 
\lipsum[5][1-3]\par\lipsum[5][4-5]\\\cmidrule{2-4}
Niv\.a 1 & 
\lipsum[6][1-2]\par\lipsum[7][1-8] & 
\lipsum[8][1-2]\par\lipsum[9][1-2] & 
\lipsum[10][1-3]\par\lipsum[11][1-3]\\\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\addlinespace` instead of `\cmidrule{2-3}`?  `\bf` is obsolete ... +1

Comment: @Zarko  I am using really `\bfseries`,  not `\bf`  (see line 2).   About `\addlinespace`, indeed, in general. But for this case I wanted to avoid confusion about the paragraph skips between and  within cells.

Comment: I see now, however, I will not do this (redefine TeX command with LaTeX's one).

Comment: @Zarko A vice derived from laziness ... `:)`

Comment: Thank you for showing me this option, I will readup on this!

Comment: Are there any possibility to scale table width (let's say I want it to be 80% of total page width)? Which param could I edit, cant figure it out.

Comment: @PetterÖstergren Change  `\linewidth` by `0.8\linewidth` (you can omit the zero).

Comment: @Fran: Could you prehapse go into a bit more depth on what the different args in `{tabulary}{args..}`. I tried to extend this into a 5 column (without \bf  the first col) 

Heres a screenshot https://imgur.com/a/T8TlVGF I don't understand why col 1 dont wrap

Comment: @PetterÖstergren `tabulary` can use the `l`,`c` and `r` columns  of  the basic  `tabular` environment , with cells of  *unbreakable single lines* and `L`, `C`, `R`  columns that can have breakable lines and even paragraphs.  There are more column types:  p, J, m, b   ... Run `texdoc lshort` (see pages 34-37) and  then  `texdoc array`  (see pages 1--3) and  `texdoc tabulary`  (see pages 1--4).

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to tex.se! Obviously this a very open question. Some decisions about the design certainly don't have a blanket solution and have to be reassessed depending on the content of the table and the goal you are trying to achieve with it: Do you want centered text? Rules or spaces separating rows or columns? Should the cells be somehow otherwise distinguished from each other, for example with a background colour? Does the amount of text vary a lot from cell to cell? Is a table really the best way of displaying this text? Is it going to be displayed on a poster, in an article, etc.?

Like in other aspects of typography, there is hardly a single best way for all possible situations.

But here's one possible example nontheless:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\noindent \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l X X X @{}}
\toprule
\textbf{Klasse} & \textbf{Konfidesialitet} & \textbf{Integritet} & \textbf{Tilgjenglighet} \\
\midrule
\textbf{Niva 1}
& Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
& Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
& Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. \\
\textbf{Niva 2}
& Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
& Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
& Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There are of course many ways you could further improve or change this example (for example using `tabulary` instead of `tabularx`)... Maybe also have a look at [Beautiful table samples](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/112343/172164) or similar threads and see if you find something that suits you there.

Comment: Thanks for the warm welcome! It's a very open question indeed, this looks like a great starting point and thanks for the reference to "Beautiful table samples". Seams like a perfect place to find out more!