# How to generate beautiful tables in LaTeX

Tags: tables

I want to create a table for a publication.

This is what I have:

```
\begin{table}[!h]
            \small
            \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}
            \begin{center}
                \begin{tabular}{|p{0.5cm} | p{2.5cm} | p{3.2cm} | p{3.2cm} | p{1cm} | p{1cm} |}
                    \hline
                    \textbf{nº} & \textbf{CID Ligando} & \textbf{Nombre Ligando} & \textbf{Afinidad (Kcal/mol)²} & \textbf{RMSD l.b.} & \textbf{RMSD u.b.}  \\ \hline
                    1 & 234523 & LoreIpsum & 234 & 0 & 0 \\
                    2 & 2345 & LoreIpsum & 2365 & 0 & 0 \\
                    3 & 3453 & LoreIpsum & 45634 & 0 & 0 \\
                    4 & 83452 & LoreIpsum & 2456 & 0 & 0 \\
                    5 & 210 & LoreIpsum & 245 & 0 & 0 \\
                    6 & 3417 & LoreIpsum & 45634 & 0 & 0 \\
                    7 & 4345 & LoreIpsum & 3456 & 0 & 0 \\
                    8 & 4334 & LoreIpsum & 3456 & 0 & 0 \\
                    \hline
                \end{tabular}
                \newline\newline
                \caption{Valores de afinidad obtenidos para los ocho fármacos en \textit{Autodock Vina}}
                \label{tab:PECs}
            \end{center}
        \end{table}
```

But I would like something like:

[image]

Is there a way of getting this? The color and the lines specially...

Btw, I use TexStudio and MikTex.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[lmargin=2cm, rmargin=2cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british,UKenglish,USenglish,english,american]{babel}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to have? The spacing? The lines (see `booktabs`-package)? The colored background? The caption?

Comment: Remove all `|`. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112343/beautiful-table-samples

Comment: Take a look at the `booktabs` documentation for general tips about table design, and particularly for the horizontal rules created with `\toprule`, `\midrule` and `\bottomrule`. Also take a look at `siunitx`'s `S` type column for numerical columns. Take a look at the `array` package to inject code for formatting of a column (e.g., to make the column print bold), last take a look at the `collcell` package to assign the effects of a macro to a complete column (e.g., for your molecular formulae).

Comment: Using the `center` environment inside of `table` results in extra vertical white space. You may want to replace the `center` environment with the `\centering` command.

Comment: What's the purpose of `p` type columns in this particular table? If all entries are short enough to fit without needing a linebreak, why not use regular `l` type columns instead of adding unnecessary extra white space?

Comment: please tell us which document class, which font, and which fontsize you employ. And, how wide are the margins?

Comment: The spacing between the columns is much larger than needed, making it harder to run your eyes across a line.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here are some suggestions, not made in any particular order:

- Remove `center` environment, use a `\centering` instruction instead.
- Drop `\newline\newline` before `\caption`. (Aside: The presence of `\newline\newline` is causing your `tabular` environment not to be centered horizontally even though it's embedded in a `center` environment.)
- Remove all vertical lines and suppress whitespace padding at edges of  table.
- Load the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/) package and replace `\hline` with `\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule` as needed, add a bit of vertical whitespace halfway through the table via `\addlinespace`.

  Aside: The user guide of the `booktabs` package is chock-full of good advice on table design. It' well worth a read -- and re-read!
- Remove the `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7}` and `\small` directives.
- Load the `siunitx` package and use the `S` column type for columns 2 and 4.
- No vulgar-looking **bold-facing** of header cells, please.
- The appears to be no need for automatic line-breaking in cells.
- Employ the `threeparttable` environment to assure that the caption won't be wider than the `tabular` material. (Aside: the `threeparttable` environment can do additional things beyond assuring that the caption's width doesn't exceed width of table.)
- Impose more structure/hierarchy on the header cells of the final two columns. ("l.b." and "u.b." stands for "lower bound" and "upper bound", right?)

The framelines in the following screenshot indicate the edges of the text block. They get inserted because I set the `showframe` option when loading the `geometry` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=2cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[british,UKenglish,USenglish,english,american]{babel}
% why not '\usepackage[spanish]{babel}'?

% New:
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,array,threeparttable}
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\textcolor{red}{\Large\textbf{before}}
\begin{table}[!h]
            \small
            \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.7} 
            \begin{center}
                \begin{tabular}{|p{0.5cm} | p{2.5cm} | p{3.2cm} | p{3.2cm} | p{1cm} | p{1cm} |} 
                    \hline
                    \textbf{nº} & \textbf{CID Ligando} & \textbf{Nombre Ligando} & \textbf{Afinidad (Kcal/mol)²} & \textbf{RMSD l.b.} & \textbf{RMSD u.b.}  \\ \hline
                    1 & 234523 & LoreIpsum & 234 & 0 & 0 \\
                    2 & 2345 & LoreIpsum & 2365 & 0 & 0 \\
                    3 & 3453 & LoreIpsum & 45634 & 0 & 0 \\
                    4 & 83452 & LoreIpsum & 2456 & 0 & 0 \\
                    5 & 210 & LoreIpsum & 245 & 0 & 0 \\
                    6 & 3417 & LoreIpsum & 45634 & 0 & 0 \\
                    7 & 4345 & LoreIpsum & 3456 & 0 & 0 \\
                    8 & 4334 & LoreIpsum & 3456 & 0 & 0 \\
                    \hline
                \end{tabular}
                \newline\newline
                \caption{Valores de afinidad obtenidos para los ocho fármacos en \textit{Autodock Vina}}
                \label{tab:version1}
            \end{center}
\end{table}

%% after
\noindent
\textcolor{red}{\Large\textbf{after}}
\begin{table}[!h]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l S[table-format=6.0] l S[table-format=5.0] cc @{}} 
\toprule
{nº} & {CID Ligando} & {Nombre Ligando} & {Afinidad} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{RMSD} \\ 
\cmidrule(l){5-6}
& & & {(Kcal/mol)\textsuperscript{2}} & {l.b.} & {u.b.}\\
\midrule
  1 & 234523 & LoremIpsum & 234   & 0 & 0 \\
  2 & 2345   & LoremIpsum & 2365  & 0 & 0 \\ 
  3 & 3453   & LoremIpsum & 45634 & 0 & 0 \\
  4 & 83452  & LoremIpsum & 2456  & 0 & 0 \\
\addlinespace
  5 & 210    & LoremIpsum & 245   & 0 & 0 \\
  6 & 3417   & LoremIpsum & 45634 & 0 & 0 \\
  7 & 4345   & LoremIpsum & 3456  & 0 & 0 \\
  8 & 4334   & LoremIpsum & 3456  & 0 & 0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Valores de afinidad obtenidos para los ocho fármacos en \textit{Autodock Vina}}
\label{tab:version2}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: What is wrong with bold-facing of header cells? Most tables in (published) books and on Wikipedia are like that.

Comment: @PeterMortensen - The main issue is that *if* a table is designed sufficiently well, bold-facing the header cells is absolutely unnecessary in order to get the information across. (Aside: Sadly, many tables in published books do *not* qualify as being "designed sufficiently well".) As with many other aspects of good typography, a well-designed table has *balance*, letting readers notice and absorb *all of the table's information*, not just the header cells. By bold-facing the header cells, one is likely doing oneself a disservice, as readers tend to focus too much on the **bold** stuff.

Comment: @PeterMortensen - For more on the subject of well-designed tables, do please study the user guide of the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/booktabs/) package. You'll likely notice that the author does *not* use **bold-facing** in a single (well-designed) table. Nuff said.

Answer (score 13):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[lmargin=2cm, rmargin=2cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tcolorbox}[arc=0pt,boxrule=0pt]
  \sisetup{group-minimum-digits = 4}
  \centering
  \caption{Valores de afinidad obtenidos para los ocho fármacos en \textit{Autodock Vina}}
  \label{tab:PECs}
  \begin{tabular}{lllS[table-format=5]ll} 
    \toprule
    \thead{nº} & \thead{CID Ligando} & \thead{Nombre Ligando} & {\thead{Afinidad\\ \unit{(Kcal\per\mole)\squared}}} & \thead{RMSD l.b.} & \thead{RMSD u.b.}  \\
    \midrule
    1 & 234523 & LoreIpsum & 234   & 0 & 0 \\
    2 & 2345   & LoreIpsum & 2365  & 0 & 0 \\
    3 & 3453   & LoreIpsum & 45634 & 0 & 0 \\
    4 & 83452  & LoreIpsum & 2456  & 0 & 0 \\
    5 & 210    & LoreIpsum & 245   & 0 & 0 \\
    6 & 3417   & LoreIpsum & 45634 & 0 & 0 \\
    7 & 4345   & LoreIpsum & 3456  & 0 & 0 \\
    8 & 4334   & LoreIpsum & 3456  & 0 & 0 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

[image]

1. Use the `booktabs` package, you will love the rules!
2. Employ `adjustbox` to manage column width
3. Trust existing tools and do not add new lines yourself
4. Trust automatic column width for column width
5. Do not change font size unless absolutely necessary

here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!h]
  \begin{adjustbox}{center,max width=\linewidth}
    \begin{tabular}{rrlrrr}
      \toprule
      \bf nº & \bf \stackbox[r]{CID\\ Ligando} & \bf \stackbox[l]{Nombre\\ Ligando }& \bf \stackbox[r]{Afinidad \\(Kcal/mol)²} 
              & \bf \stackbox[l]{RMSD \\ l.b.} & \bf \stackbox[r]{RMSD \\u.b.} \\
      \midrule
      1      & 234523          & LoreIpsum          & 234                      & 0             & 0             \\
      2      & 2345            & LoreIpsum          & 2365                     & 0             & 0             \\
      3      & 3453            & LoreIpsum          & 45634                    & 0             & 0             \\
      4      & 83452           & LoreIpsum          & 2456                     & 0             & 0             \\
      5      & 210             & LoreIpsum          & 245                      & 0             & 0             \\
      6      & 3417            & LoreIpsum          & 45634                    & 0             & 0             \\
      7      & 4345            & LoreIpsum          & 3456                     & 0             & 0             \\
      8      & 4334            & LoreIpsum          & 3456                     & 0             & 0             \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \end{adjustbox}
  \caption{Valores de afinidad obtenidos para los ocho fármacos en \textit{Autodock Vina}}
  \label{tab:PECs}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't use `adjustbox`. It change font size too, so the consistency of them in table and in text is lost.

Comment: You may also want to replace `\bf` with `\bfseries` or use `\textbf`. See also: [“Correct” way to bold/italicize text?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41681/134144)

Comment: I prefer the archaic `\bf` for headers. It is the shortest way to create bold face headers, and length matters, if you wish to set your table in columns also in the input.

Comment: Using `\bf` doesn't work if you use a document class that disables it (and its "friends" `\rm`, `\it`, etc, not to mention similar commands in math mode). There are plenty of websites already that teach people how to write obsolete LaTeX that barely works. I don't think the world needs another one.

Comment: You are absolutely right. Perhaps a more robust and a bit shorter way, is `\let\B=\bfseries` and then use `\B` in header cells.

Answer (score 1):

Your statement

```
"I want to create a table for a publication."
```

does not specify if said publication is / is not for a publication in a scientific journal.  But *if* this is the case, it usually is the more efficient approach to use their templates for submitting *the content* in question (example [American Chemical Society](https://pubs.acs.org/page/4authors/submission/tex.html), [Royal Society of Chemistry](https://www.rsc.org/journals-books-databases/journal-authors-reviewers/author-tools-services/), [Wiley](https://authorservices.wiley.com/author-resources/book-authors/prepare-your-manuscript/wiley-latex-template.html), [Elsevier](https://www.elsevier.com/authors/policies-and-guidelines/latex-instructions), [Springer](https://www.springer.com/gp/livingreviews/latex-templates), [IUCr](https://journals.iucr.org/a/services/latexstyle.html), [MDPI](https://www.mdpi.com/authors/latex)).*  A search e.g., on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/search?phrase=submission) equally yields examples, and on occasion you find templates for books ([example](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/wiley-book-style)).  You may use these templates for the preparation of the supplementary information of your publication, too.

In occurrence of e.g., overly large tables, or equations better displayed across two columns instead of one, their staff members (or, contractors like
[River Valley](https://rivervalleytechnologies.com/tag/latex/) or [le-tex](https://www.le-tex.de/en/index.html)) already have experience how to rekey / (re)format the content to blend-in into the recognizable layout of the publishers, or may contact you if deemed necessary.

*) Because the table shown by you suggests a publication in chemistry.