# How do I make this table better looking?

Tags: tables, tabularx

Everything is very squished together, does anybody have any suggestions on what I can do?
[image]

Here is my code for the table:

```
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textit{\textbf{l (m)}} & \textit{\textbf{$\overline{t}$$_{10}$}\:(s)}} & \textit{\textbf{$\Delta t_{10}\:(s)$}} & \textit{\textbf{$T\:(s)$}} & \textit{\textbf{$\Delta T\:(s)$}} & \textit{\textbf{$l^2$\:$(m^2)$}} & \textit{\textbf{$T^2\:(m\:s^2)$}} & \textit{\textbf{$\Delta T^2\:l\:(m\:s^2)$}} & \textit{\textbf{$\sigma \: (s)$}} \\ \hline
0.450                   & 15.414                                        & 0.1739                                 & 1.541                      & 0.01739                           & 0.2025                                          & 1.069                             & 0.02412                                     & 0.1168                            \\ \hline
0.400                   & 14.84                                         & 0.3927                                 & 1.483                      & 0.03927                           & 0.1600                                          & 0.8810                            & 0.04661                                     & 0.1916                            \\ \hline
0.350                   & 14.75                                         & 0.6523                                 & 1.475                      & 0.06523                           & 0.1225                                          & 0.7613                            & 0.06733                                     & 0.3522                            \\ \hline
0.300                   & 14.38                                         & 0.09190                                & 1.437                      & 0.009190                          & 0.0900                                          & 0.6200                            & 0.00793                                     & 0.0566                            \\ \hline
0.250                   & 14.18                                         & 0.5368                                 & 1.418                      & 0.05368                           & 0.0625                                          & 0.5029                            & 0.03807                                     & 0.3006                            \\ \hline
0.200                   & 13.82                                         & 0.2223                                 & 1.381                      & 0.02223                           & 0.0400                                          & 0.3819                            & 0.01229                                     & 0.1302                            \\ \hline
-0.200                  & 13.79                                         & 0.2098                                 & 1.379                      & 0.02098                           & -0.0400                                         & -0.3805                           & -0.01157                                    & 0.1170                            \\ \hline
-0.250                  & 14.24                                         & 0.1223                                 & 1.424                      & 0.01223                           & -0.0625                                         & -0.5070                           & -0.00870                                    & 0.07902                           \\ \hline
-0.300                  & 14.55                                         & 0.2556                                 & 1.455                      & 0.02556                           & -0.0900                                         & -0.6352                           & -0.02231                                    & 0.1646                            \\ \hline
-0.350                  & 14.56                                         & 0.4752                                 & 1.456                      & 0.04752                           & -0.1225                                         & -0.7419                           & -0.04843                                    & 0.2631                            \\ \hline
-0.400                  & 14.84                                         & 0.1492                                 & 1.484                      & 0.01492                           & -0.1600                                         & -0.8810                           & -0.01771                                    & 0.08889                           \\ \hline
-0.450                  & 15.41                                         & 0.2191                                 & 1.541                      & 0.02191                           & -0.2025                                         & -1.069                            & -0.03034                                    & 0.1271                            \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

the result is a squidged table.

Comment: Please tell us what `m` and `s` mean. E.g., are they the symbols for "meter" and "second", respectively?

Comment: Incidentally, `\textbf` and `\textit` are text-mode commands; they have no effect on material that's rendered in math mode.

Comment: Yes, @Mico, meter and second. For context its an experiment on a physical pendulum. To linaerise the graph, im plotting T^2l vs l and the unit for T^2 l is meter seconds squared.

Comment: There are countless threads on the issue. Check these (and the links) out for some inspiration: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112343/beautiful-table-samples https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/604496/how-to-generate-beautiful-tables-in-latex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I would round numbers, for example to four decimals
- for table use `tblr` and prescribed equal width to all columns

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}           

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
    \sisetup{round-integer-to-decimal,
             round-mode=places,
             round-precision = 4,
             table-format= 1.4
             }
\begin{tblr}{colspec = { *{9}{X[c, si]} @{}},
             row{1}  = {guard, mode=math},
             row{2}  = {guard, mode=text},
             row{3-Z}= {rowsep=0pt},
             row{odd[3-Z]} = {abovesep=1ex},
             }
    \toprule
l 
    &   \bar{t}_{10} 
        &   \Delta t_{10} 
            &   T 
                &   \Delta T 
                    &   l^2 
                        &   T^2 
                            &   \Delta T^2 
                                &   \sigma 
                                \\
(\unit{\meter})
    &   (\unit{\second})
        &   (\unit{\second})
            &   (\unit{\second})
                &   (\unit{\second})
                    &   (\unit{\meter\square\second})
                        &   (\unit{\meter\square\second})
                            &   (\unit{\meter\square\second})
                                &   (\unit{\second})
                                    \\
    \midrule
0.450   & 15.414    & 0.1739    & 1.541 & 0.01739   & 0.2025    & 1.069     & 0.02412   & 0.1168    \\
0.400   & 14.84     & 0.3927    & 1.483 & 0.03927   & 0.1600    & 0.8810    & 0.04661   & 0.1916    \\
0.350   & 14.75     & 0.6523    & 1.475 & 0.06523   & 0.1225    & 0.7613    & 0.06733   & 0.3522    \\
0.300   & 14.38     & 0.09190   & 1.437 & 0.009190  & 0.0900    & 0.6200    & 0.00793   & 0.0566    \\
0.250   & 14.18     & 0.5368    & 1.418 & 0.05368   & 0.0625    & 0.5029    & 0.03807   & 0.3006    \\
0.200   & 13.82     & 0.2223    & 1.381 & 0.02223   & 0.0400    & 0.3819    & 0.01229   & 0.1302    \\
-0.200  & 13.79     & 0.2098    & 1.379 & 0.02098   & -0.0400   & -0.3805   & -0.01157  & 0.1170    \\
-0.250  & 14.24     & 0.1223    & 1.424 & 0.01223   & -0.0625   & -0.5070   & -0.00870  & 0.07902   \\
-0.300  & 14.55     & 0.2556    & 1.455 & 0.02556   & -0.0900   & -0.6352   & -0.02231  & 0.1646    \\
-0.350  & 14.56     & 0.4752    & 1.456 & 0.04752   & -0.1225   & -0.7419   & -0.04843  & 0.2631    \\
-0.400  & 14.84     & 0.1492    & 1.484 & 0.01492   & -0.1600   & -0.8810   & -0.01771  & 0.08889   \\
-0.450  & 15.41     & 0.2191    & 1.541 & 0.02191   & -0.2025   & -1.069    & -0.03034  & 0.1271    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do check the labels and units in columns 6, 7, and 8. For sure, it's got to be meter times squared second, not meter per squared second.

Comment: Thank you all so much, these tables are so nice.

Comment: @Mico, you are right! I should look table which OP provide,  not only mess of column headers code ... Corrected now. Thank you very much for note!

Comment: Hey @Zarko, how do I add T^2l and delta T^2l to this? I tried to edit it in the document but it just says no pdf produced.

edit - I tried editing a bit more but i'm not sure where to add my data, and adding T^2 l and delta T ^2 l makes the table go out of the page.

Comment: @NealBatra, as far as I see, columns width  `T^2`  and `\Delta ^2` already exist in table. Do you like to add new columns to table? Without to see what you doing, I can't say what is going wrong. BTW, your table is quite wide and you not provide any information about your document page layout.

Comment: @Zarko I am an idiot, theres no better way to put it. I spent 3 hours trying to fix this and I  just realised that where you put T^2 and delta T^2 it was meant to say T^2 l and delta T^2 l. It's fixed now. Many Thanks haha and sorry about that.

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to suggest that you start by getting rid of all vertical rules and most horizontal rules. Next, use the macros `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\addlinespace`, and `\bottomrule` instead of `\hline`, as is done in the example code below. Never forget that whitespace can be every bit as effective at providing a visual separator as a solid line does.

Next, use the machinery of the `siunitx` package -- specifically, its `S` column type -- to align the numbers on their respective decimal markers. Finally, do provide some more structure to the header material; I suggest you list the variables in one row and their units of measurement in a second row, where you'd use the `\unit` macro (also provided by the `siunitx` package) to format the units according to typographically well established standards.

Does the table now look less squished than it did before?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % set text block size parameters as appropriate
\usepackage{amsmath,array,booktabs,siunitx}
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1,group-digits=false]}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} T{-1.3} T{2.3} T{1.4} T{1.3} T{1.5} T{-1.4} T{-1.4} T{-1.5} T{1.5} @{}}
\toprule
{$l$} & {$\bar{t}_{10}$} & {$\Delta t_{10}$} & 
{$T$} & {$\Delta T$} & {$l^2$} & 
{$T^2$} & {$\Delta T^2\,l$} & {$\sigma$}\\ 
{(\unit{\meter})} & {(\unit{\second})} &{(\unit{\second})} & 
{(\unit{\second})} & {(\unit{\second})} & {(\unit{\meter\squared})} & 
{(\unit{\second\squared})} & {(\unit{\meter\second\squared})} & {(\unit{\second})}\\
\midrule
 0.450 & 15.414& 0.1739 & 1.541 & 0.01739 &  0.2025 &  1.069  &  0.02412 & 0.1168 \\ 
 0.400 & 14.84 & 0.3927 & 1.483 & 0.03927 &  0.1600 &  0.8810 &  0.04661 & 0.1916 \\ 
 0.350 & 14.75 & 0.6523 & 1.475 & 0.06523 &  0.1225 &  0.7613 &  0.06733 & 0.3522 \\ 
 \addlinespace
 0.300 & 14.38 & 0.0919 & 1.437 & 0.00919 &  0.0900 &  0.6200 &  0.00793 & 0.0566 \\ 
 0.250 & 14.18 & 0.5368 & 1.418 & 0.05368 &  0.0625 &  0.5029 &  0.03807 & 0.3006 \\ 
 0.200 & 13.82 & 0.2223 & 1.381 & 0.02223 &  0.0400 &  0.3819 &  0.01229 & 0.1302 \\ 
 \addlinespace
-0.200 & 13.79 & 0.2098 & 1.379 & 0.02098 & -0.0400 & -0.3805 & -0.01157 & 0.1170 \\ 
-0.250 & 14.24 & 0.1223 & 1.424 & 0.01223 & -0.0625 & -0.5070 & -0.00870 & 0.07902\\ 
-0.300 & 14.55 & 0.2556 & 1.455 & 0.02556 & -0.0900 & -0.6352 & -0.02231 & 0.1646 \\ 
\addlinespace
-0.350 & 14.56 & 0.4752 & 1.456 & 0.04752 & -0.1225 & -0.7419 & -0.04843 & 0.2631 \\ 
-0.400 & 14.84 & 0.1492 & 1.484 & 0.01492 & -0.1600 & -0.8810 & -0.01771 & 0.08889\\ 
-0.450 & 15.41 & 0.2191 & 1.541 & 0.02191 & -0.2025 & -1.069  & -0.03034 & 0.1271 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```